# How to fill a container with dynamic tiles (like Masonry)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, masonry

I have a container that will contain a dynamic number of square tiles (could be 1, 5, 12 ect..).

I would like it to be a three column layout but understand that the number of tiles may not be divisible by three. In an instance where it isn't able to be divisible by three I would like the remaining elements to spread to fill the gaps.

Here is a basic JSfiddel https://jsfiddle.net/2w8p0tx2/.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 item">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 item">2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 item">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 item">4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 item">5</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 item">6</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 item">7</div>
</div>
```

Is there a library that scale elements to fit the container?

Any help would be appreciated.